# Read a specific line or character from a text file, not recognizing the text

Tags: python, function, text, methods

veriftype works, but veriftype2 doesn't. Is it because my method to read the second line isn't accurate? The text file it's reading from has one character on each line, either an x or an o on each. I tried using just f.read(2) but it seems like neither one does the trick. I can't seem to find any other source of problem, since when I print the variable that should be the value of the line, it gives me the correct value, but the if statement doesn't run, and it just skips to the else part.

```
def veriftype(self):
    f = open("Transfert.txt", "r")
    y = f.readline(1)
    print (y)
    if y == "x":
        if type(self) == Retriever or type(self) == Shepherd:
            self.points += 1
            print("It worked for the dogs.")
        else:
            print("It recognized the type wasn't correct, so it didn't get any points.")
    elif y == "o":
        print("It recognized the o")
    else:
        print("It didn't recognize anything")
    print(self.points)


def veriftype2(self):
    with open("Transfert.txt") as f:
        ligne = f.readlines()
    z = ligne[2]
    print(z)
    if ligne[2] == "x":
        if type(self) == Perroquet or type(self) == Macaw:
            self.points += 1
            print("It worked for the birds.")
        else:
            print("It recognized the type wasn't correct, so it didn't get any points.")
    elif ligne[2] == "o":
        print("It recognized the o")
    else:
        print("It didn't recognize anything")
    # print(self.points)
```

Comment: The 1st function gets the first character of the first line; the 2nd function gets the ***whole*** of the third line (i.e. indexed from zero). You should always use `repr()` when debugging text values, so that you can see any non-printable characters. Thus, `print(repr(y))` would output `'x'` for the 1st function, and `print(repr(z))` would output `'x\n'` for the 2nd function. If there's only one character per line, you can do `f.read().split()` to put them all in a list. This will automatically remove all whitespace (including blank lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, but it cannot recognize the characters because readlines() also includes a newline character, so it reads 'x\n' rather than 'x'. Therefore there is no literal match. Replace `.readlines()` with `.read().splitlines()` to solve this.